# Modifying the Wagtail publish dropdown (per app)

Tags: django, wagtail

I'd like to reconfigure the default "Publish" menu. The default configuration is this:

[image: Default publish menu]

I'd like to make Publish the default action, and move it to the top. I'd also like to remove Submit for Moderation, as our site has no current need for that feature.

Ideally, I'd love to be able to override the menu config on a per-app basis - we will likely have other sections of our site in the future where we want a different config.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>This isn't currently possible I'm afraid - the menu items are fixed in [wagtailadmin/pages/create.html](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailadmin/templates/wagtailadmin/pages/create.html) and [edit.html](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailadmin/templates/wagtailadmin/pages/edit.html).</s>

This is possible as of Wagtail 2.4 using the `register_page_action_menu_item` hook, as per [Yannic Hamann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55219342/1853523). Additionally, Wagtail 2.7 (not released at time of writing) provides a `construct_page_listing_buttons` hook for modifying existing options.

Comment: presumably you could copy and override those templates?  as in http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html

Answer (score 5):

You can add a new item to the action menu by registering a custom menu item with the help of wagtail hooks.
To do so create a file named `wagtail_hooks.py` within any of your existing Django apps.

```
from wagtail.core import hooks
from wagtail.admin.action_menu import ActionMenuItem

class GuacamoleMenuItem(ActionMenuItem):
    label = "Guacamole"

    def get_url(self, request, context):
        return "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNJdJIwCF_Y"


@hooks.register('register_page_action_menu_item')
def register_guacamole_menu_item():
    return GuacamoleMenuItem(order=10)
```

[Source](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/hooks.html#register-page-action-menu-item)

If you want to remove an existing menu item:

```
@hooks.register('construct_page_action_menu')
def remove_submit_to_moderator_option(menu_items, request, context):
    menu_items[:] = [item for item in menu_items if item.name != 'action-submit']
```

The default button `SAVE DRAFT` is still hardcoded and therefore cannot be configured so easily. See [here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/pages/edit.html#L41).

Answer (score 2):

It seems it can't be done on server side without some monkey-patching.

However if you want it for yourself (or have access to computers of those who will publish) you can modify your browser instead.

1. Install [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) browser addon
2. Create new script with a content below
3. Change `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/*` to your wagtail admin panel url pattern
4. Save script and check admin panel

---

Result should look:

[image]

---

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Wagtail: replace "Save draft" with "Publish"
// @match    *://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==


let $ = window.jQuery;


function modify() {
    let draft = $("button.button-longrunning:contains('Save draft')");
    let publish = $("button.button-longrunning:contains('Publish')");

    if (draft.length && publish.length) {
        swap(publish, draft);
    }
};


function swap(a, b) {
    a = $(a); b = $(b);
    var tmp = $('<span>').hide();
    a.before(tmp);
    b.before(a);
    tmp.replaceWith(b);
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        try {
            modify();
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.error(e, e.stack);
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: you could also put your script in a file and let it load through the `insert_editor_js` hook. That way all users, even those without Tampermonkey installed, can profit.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the code above, these selectors works for every admin language:

```
let draft = $("button.button-longrunning.action-save");
let publish = $("button.button-longrunning[name='action-publish']");
```